# Drop down box logic, using javascript to add and subtract

Tags: javascript, html

Im just stuck a bit in trying to figure out the best way to do something. On my page i have 2 drop down boxes and a total text field.

When i select an option from a drop down box i want the total to be updated accordingly, i think this i have done so far, but i failed to think about if they change their mind and change the same drop down box again.

My HTML page looks as so

```
<body>
<div id = "form">
<form id = "test">
<p>
<label>Case:</label>
<select id="box1" onchange="code(1)">
  <option value="0.00">No Case - $0.00</option>
  <option value="300.00">Case 1 - $300.00</option>
  <option value="100.00">Case 2 - $100.00</option>
  <option value="600.00">Case 3 - $600.00</option>
  <option value="50.00">Case 4 - $50.00</option>
</select>

<label>Color:</label>
<select id="box2" onchange="code(2)">
    <option value="20.00">Red - $20.00</option>
    <option value="50.00">Green - $50.00</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="cost" id="cost" onfocus="this.blur()"/>    
</p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

My javascript looks like this

```
function code(num){
var boxnum = "box"+num;

if (boxnum == "box1")
{
var b = document.getElementById("box1");
}
else if(boxnum == "box2")
{
var b = document.getElementById("box2");
}


var boxcost = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
var cost = document.getElementById('cost').value;
cost = parseFloat(cost) + parseFloat(boxcost)
document.getElementById('cost').value = cost;
}
```

As it stands i can select case 3 from box1 and it adds $600 but if i change my mind and then say no case it just adds 0 to the 600 thats there.

Sorry if its a really obvious question just been stuck doing it all day trying to make it work and am a bit brain dead.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're always adding the current cost cell to whichever value was just changed - you should be adding the two `box` values together regardless of which one changed.

```
function code() {   // forget the parameter

    var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
    var box2 = document.getElementById('box2');
    var cost = document.getElementById('cost');

    var total = parseFloat(box1.value) + parseFloat(box2.value);
    cost.value = total;
}
```

There's no need to use `selectedIndex`, just use the options' `value` properties directly.

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/J4zyy/

Answer (score 0):

The thing to do is maintain a record of the previous value in order that you can subtract it. That needs to be in a global variable in order that it's maintained between function calls.

Start out with a previous value of zero, and every time the `select` is changed, subtract the previous value and add the current value.

```
var prevboxcost = 0;
function code(num){
    var boxnum = "box"+num;
    if (boxnum == "box1")
    {
    var b = document.getElementById("box1");
    }
    else if(boxnum == "box2")
    {
    var b = document.getElementById("box2");
    }


    var boxcost = parseFloat(b.options[b.selectedIndex].value);
    var cost = parseFloat(document.getElementById('cost').value);
    // do the addition but subtract the old value
    cost = cost + boxcost - prevboxcost;
    // now set prev variable so you can subtract it next time round
    prevboxcost = boxcost;
    document.getElementById('cost').value = cost;
}
```

I would probably pass `this` to the function because that is the `select` element itself and you don't need to find it.

Comment: no, it's far easier just to use the two values already in the form - look how short my answer is compared to this!

Comment: @Alnitak: You're quite right. However it's probably useful to leave this answer here for comparison purposes and search results.

Answer (score -1):

if i understood correctly, you want to update a text box value respect to selected list value

```
<select id="box1">
<option value="0.00">No Case - $0.00</option>
<option value="300.00">Case 1 - $300.00</option>
<option value="100.00">Case 2 - $100.00</option>
<option value="600.00">Case 3 - $600.00</option>
<option value="50.00">Case 4 - $50.00</option>
</select>
<select id="box2">
<option value="20.00">Red - $20.00</option>
<option value="50.00">Green - $50.00</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="cost" id="cost"/>
```

you can use Jquery code, im just suggesting if you use jquery here it'll easy though

```
$('#box2').change(function(){
  total = parseInt($("#box1 option:selected").val())+parseInt($("#box2 option:selected").val());
$('#cost').val(total);
});
$('#box1').change(function(){
  $('#cost').val($("#box1 option:selected").val());
});
```

working example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fosterz/v8rBG/3/)